# Change DisplayFor Text/Value through jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need this displayfor to update its value from using jquery.

I tried `.val()` and `.text()` but neither worked, is there a special way to do this for Displays, I need it to be and stay as a Display.

Also can the style not be set for Displays? I never could get that to work, it works for TextboxFor.

Thanks for any tips.

```
Estimated Time: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EstimatedTime, new { @class = "TitleEstTimeClass", @style = "color: green" })

$(".TitleEstTimeClass").val(result[1]);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`DisplayFor` generates a label HTML tag `<label id="myId" class="myClass">Some Text</label>`. **(INCORRECT)**

**EDIT**

I was wrong and thought you were using the `LabelFor` helper.  The `DisplayFor` helper outputs no HTML markup (like a label or span tag).  If you want this to work with the `DisplayFor` helper, you will need to wrap the `DisplayFor` tag with a `<span>` or something similar like below:

```
<span class="TitleEstTimeClass" style="color: green">
   @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EstimatedTime)
</span>
```

Given this, try using the `.html()` JQuery property like below - it really is no different than updating the text in div or span:

```
$(".TitleEstTimeClass").html(result[1]);
```

Also, be sure that your JQuery call is in the appropriate `<script></script>` tags and that the function that you are calling is actually being fired.  I am not sure if the above code is straight from your project or just snippets, but as written above, nothing will happen.

Comment: using just the <label></label> how can I then call my model => model.EstimatedTime though? and have it in "Some Text"

Comment: oh well it didn't work keeping like I had it, however the .html did work when I just created a normal label and just put a DisplayTextFor inside of it.

Comment: Just updated my answer - please see the EDIT for more details as to why is still wasn't working for you and why you had to do what you did in your last comment.  PS - I would use a span tag over a label tag for consistency (this is not asssociated with a form field, thus is not really a label)

Comment: Thank you, It's very helpful for me.

Comment: You can use span Id and set value $("#spanId").val("sometext"); as well