# Display value obtained from Jquery call in DisplayFor and not TextBoxFor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following Jquery that returns values from a dialog Box and fills in the values in the main page :

```
function AutoCompleteTopayer(pName, addLine, pCity, pState, pZip, pPhone) {
        $(".PayerName").html(pName);
        $("#txtPayerAddress").val(addLine);
        $("#txtPayerCity").val(pCity);
        $("#txtPayerState").val(pState);
        $("#txtPayerZip").val(pZip);
        $("#txtPayerPhone").val(pPhone);
        var csz = pCity + ", " + pState + ", " + pZip;
        $("#txtCStateZip").val(csz);
        $("#SearchPayDlg").dialog("close");
    }
```

Code from my View :

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.cityStateZip, new { @class = "fauxInput", id = "txtCStateZip" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.payerCityName, new { id = "txtPayerCity" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.payerStateCode, new { id = "txtPayerState" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.payerPostalZoneOrZipCode, new { id = "txtPayerZip" })
```

This gives the following output:

[image: Output1]

---

When I replace the TextBoxFor with DisplayFor ... The values are not shown. I've found one  article that somehow adresses my issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374318/change-displayfor-text-value-through-jquery) ,so I've comeup with this code :

```
<span class="txtPayerName">
     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.payerName, new { @class = "fauxInput" })
 </span>
```

and in the JQuery method :

```
$(".txtPayerName").html(pName);
```

,but that doesnt work either.Any solutions ?

---

**Later Edit**: Sorry , i found out it was all about a typo... the last one actually works .. I've edited and gonna let it here so others may benefit from it.

The above code works with the sole remark that the displayFor's class will not work( thanks Darin Dimitrov), so this should work:

```
 <span class="txtPayerName fauxInput">
         @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.payerName)
     </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of the `DisplayFor` helper doesn't do at all what you think it does (apply CSS class). It allows you to pass additional ViewData to the display template.

So you could apply the CSS to the containing element

```
<span class="txtPayerName fauxInput">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.payerName)
</span>
```

and then adapt your selector:

```
$('.fauxInput').html(pName);
```

Your code also works because in your selector you used `$(".txtPayerName")` but it is important to point out that there won't be any `fauxInput` if you use this approach.

Comment: thanks .. that actually helps .. Gonna give you the answered mark :) ... in 7 minutes :(

Comment: I;ve tried adding fauxInput class to the span ... b ut it doesnt recognise it. txtPayername is a class I used to reffer to the displayFor. using : $('.txtPayerName ').html(pName) works but doesnt recognise fauxInput

Comment: Did you notice how I added the `fauxInput` class to the span in my answer?

Comment: Yes, seems legit , but I feel like I dont quite understand your selector choice : using fauxInput will put the value of the pName in all my other displayFors, will it not ?

Comment: Nevermind ... .It was a CSS selector issue.Thanks for all the help !