# How To Underline @Html.DisplayFor in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

In one criteria I have to underline `@Html.Display` for like below.

[image]

I know to do it simple label but using Razor syntax I tried lot but no luck. Please guide me. Below is my code.

```
<label style="font-size: xx-large; font-weight: 700">@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Lane_Number, new { @border_bottom:"thick solid #ff000"})</label>
```

Comment: Have you tried `new { @style = "border-bottom: thick solid #ff0000" }`?

Comment: @MelanciaUK yup. But it trowed error in view

Comment: I got no errors but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: You could refer to this other post and work out a template: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365633/what-is-the-html-displayfor-syntax-for

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a span element in order for it to work.

```
<span class="test" style="border-bottom: 4px solid #CC4040;"> 

       @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Lane_Number) 

</span>
```

Make sure if you have any elements below the DisplayFor, they are far enough down on the page or else the underline will be hidden

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374318/change-displayfor-text-value-through-jquery

Comment: totally unrelated but maybe you could help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046058/custom-assembly-attribute-to-string